# Create and show a fragment from another module

Tags: java, android, module, compilation

My App module is including a Library named Z, but in Z I need to create and show an instance of a Fragment which is defined in App, how can I do that?

I found this, but problem is I don't have `BillingFragment` defined while I am in module Z.

```
Class<?> class = Class.forName("example.package.BillingFragment");
Constructor<?> cons = class.getConstructor(BillingFragment.class);
BillingFragment object = (BillingFragment) cons.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the fragment already and you want to create an instance using a public default no arg `constructor` you can just call:

```
Constructor constructor= BillingFragment.class.getConstructor();
BillingFragment fragment = (BillingFragment)constructor.newInstance();
```

or even better use a public static `newInstance` method:

```
Method method = BillingFragment.class.getMethod("newInstance", Class<?>... parameterTypes);
BillingFragment fragment = (BillingFragment) method.invoke(null, Object... args);
```

P.S: you should **refrain** from using **hard-coded** strings like `"example.package.BillingFragment"` or `"newInstance"` as these string became invalid if the app get **obfuscated**. Otherwise remember to **keep** the class and method names in `proguard-rules` if you really need to.